# for() loops with mutable variables

Tags: javascript, loops

HTML:

```
<a id="link1" href="#">LINK1</a>
<div id="text1" style="display: none;">text1 div</div>

<a id="link2" href="#">LINK2</a>
<div id="text2" style="display: none;">text2 div</div>

<a id="link3" href="#">LINK3</a>
<div id="text3" style="display: none;">text3 div</div>
```

JS:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 500; i++) {
  $('#link' + i).click(function() {
    $('#text' + i).toggle('fast');
    return false;
  });
}
```

but it's not working. Idea is to make each #link(number) showing appropriate #text(number) block. But at this momenty my phpstorm says "i" is mutable variable.... Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like the javascript is being interpreted by php ? Can you post more source code ?

Comment: I'd use a `class` instead: `$('a.some-class').click(function () {$(this).next('div.some-class').toggle('fast')})`

Comment: SteveP, it's all i got. (whole souce code)

Comment: How to make work that "i" variable twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could do the following:

Add a class "targetLink" to every :

```
<a id="link1" class="targetLink" href="#">LINK1</a>
```

Replace the for loop targeting the class itself:

```
$("a.targetLink").toggle(function() {
    $(this).next("div").slideDown(350);
}, function() {
    $(this).next("div").slideUp(350);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VinnyFonseca/yxpCA/

EDIT: Extra functionality for closing previously opened div when clicking on another item.

```
$("a.targetLink").toggle(function() {
    $(".open").slideUp(350);
    $(this).next("div").slideDown(350).addClass("open");
}, function() {
    $(this).next("div").slideUp(350).removeClass("open");
});
```

Comment: This worked fine for me :) thanks. But it's not possible using for()?

Comment: It is possible. I just thought it would be a better solution on your case.

Comment: how also close previous opened div when u click on another?

Comment: I've edited the question to include that answer. Next time try opening another question.

Answer (score 4):

You have a [closure issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) here, to avoid it just pass `i` as data to the event handler.

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 500; i++) {
  $('#link' + i).click(i, function(e) {
    $('#text' + e.data).toggle('fast');
    return false;
  });
}
```

Comment: Error: TypeError: H.apply is not a function

Comment: Maybe its drupal conflict with it. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

First edit the href attribute attribute to make reference to the corresponding Dom element and some class to identify the anchors.

```
<a id="link1" href="#text1" class="some-class">LINK1</a>
<div id="text1" style="display: none;">text1 div</div>

<a id="link2" href="#tex2" class="some-class">LINK2</a>
<div id="text2" style="display: none;">text2 div</div>

<a id="link3" href="#tex2" class="some-class">LINK3</a>
<div id="text3" style="display: none;">text3 div</div>
```

Then modify the javascript

```
$('.some-class').click(function() {
    $( $(this).attr('href') ).toggle('fast');
});
```