# jquery - get audio file duration? [no HTML5 audio]

Tags: jquery, duration

How to get athe duration of an audio file?

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
    var files = evt.dataTransfer.files,

        dur = files.duration;

    document.getElementById('drop_zone-info').innerHTML = 'Duration: ' + dur + ' (h:m:s)';
}
```

**Test: http://jsfiddle.net/XSavU/1/**

Comment: You'll have to read the file to find out that information.

Comment: By adding a fake audio tag for and get `audio.duration`?

Comment: I was thinking using [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) but your idea sounds much easier, try it an see if it works.

Comment: Can't get the proper src for the audio tag since only `file.name` is possible without the path. Faking the path gives me "Not allowed to load local resource"

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XSavU/2/

Comment: Got it: http://jsfiddle.net/XSavU/3/ Thanks!

Comment: Now I got the next problem. I can't adress them on multiple files: http://jsfiddle.net/H7xFS/

Comment: You're trying to get the element from the dom before you add it to the dom

Comment: It seems I can't join the dur and the size into one statement :( http://jsfiddle.net/H7xFS/1/

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15482516/for-loops-with-mutable-variables/15482653#15482653 , http://api.jquery.com/on/ and then http://jsfiddle.net/H7xFS/2/

Comment: I see, on() runs an own function so the index needs to ne stored as `e.data`. That was a had sunday lesson! Thanks a lot!